# Настройка доступа в интернет через WAN1 в d link dfl-800

Tags: сеть

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить доступ в интернет через WAN1?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте маршрут в котором опишите все доступные сети через шлюз "адрес шлюза вашего провайдера".